# Double elimination Pool Tournament

Tags: tournaments, pool

How do I set up a double elimination tournament with 18 participants. I can never get it to come out even.

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. Note that in general, any matched elimination tournament cannot come out even if it has a non-power-of-two number of participants.

Comment: @F1Krazy Questions here don't necessarily need to be about a _specific_ competitive sport; general sporting questions are fine so long as they are reasonably scoped. While it could apply to any competitive activity, it is definitely relevant to sports (I've had to deal with this more than once while organising tournaments) so I think this is on-topic here.

Comment: Is there enough in [How does a double elimination bracket work?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5811/how-does-a-double-elimination-bracket-work) to answer your question? _Practically_ the answer to this question for 99% of people is "download a bracket from the Internet and don't worry about it".

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think that's the best answer that is reasonable here - and it even shows (in the question) how a 9 team DE bracket works, which seems like a perfect analogue here.